# Download 13.04 iso with wget

Tags: downloads, iso, wget

I am trying to build a virtual machine running Ubuntu 13.04 on a server running 12.04. I don't have any GUI. How can I download the iso file to 12.04 server using wget? I want to download the 13.04 server edition 64-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the [links to all the images for Raring on this page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/).

To download 13.04 64-bit Server Edition, run the following command:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso
```

You may further refer the [manpage for the `wget` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wget)

Comment: Is this address pretty standardized. Like I could easily change it for any release or version I want.

Comment: Mostly Yes. But it doesn't work in all the cases. For example, after the 2nd point release of 12.04 LTS, `ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso` is no longer available on that server. However, the link for all the images is standardized. You may access that link for any distribution using `releases.ubuntu.com/<distribution adjective>`. Eg: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

32bit `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso`

64bit `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso`