# ubuntu 32bit 13.04 iso image for virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

> Hello folks
>
> From where i can download 32bit for 13.04 version for my virtual box.
> Only 32bit.
>
> Thanks
>
> shazz

Comment: As said in the answer to the question Alvar linked to, just go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop an choose your "flavour" 32-bit. It's free and offcial there (donations are welcome but they are in no way needed). But you should know that 13.04 is no loger supported.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the 13.04 32bit version from this link:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link [Site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/)

Download this file :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard desktop iso and installing in virtual box you will have to run the commands `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`. After this it will become usable.

There are prebuilt virtual box images availible from many sites, but no "offical image" so to say.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find all linux iso image 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/

here they can given download iso image using wget you can also use this too
[Download 13.04 iso with wget](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305304/download-13-04-iso-with-wget)